# Making models automatically in django?

Tags: django, migration, models

Could you please tell me is there any method to create and migrate models automatically in django. Let me explain in brief:

```
class Device1_Data(models.Model):
    created_at = models.CharField(max_length=30, null=True)

    Longitude = models.CharField(max_length=20, null=True)
    Latitude = models.CharField(max_length=20, null=True)
```

Similary I wish that the same model should create for Device2_Data. and then again migrations also be taken place automatically. There should not be any necessity of running the python manage.py makemigrations.

Is it possible guys??

Comment: Why do you need multiple models that are the same?

Comment: Excuse me, but you are not getting what i mean to say. Actually I didn't explain it very well. I want to store the device 1 data in one model and device 2 data in another model. i mean for each device i want different tables and therefore models

Comment: No I understood that perfectly. But *why*? That is not how you design databases.

Comment: Then can you tell how to design it? If it is required to store each device data in different table.

Comment: I can't until you tell me why you think that is a requirement. Normally, you store data with the same structure in the same table.

Comment: Ok boss. will tell you. See. We will be having different gps devices.  Each device will be assigned to a vehicle. and again a driver will be there. so relationship will be like device to vehicle to driver. Anyway, To get the details of any device, it's expected to be saved the data from each device in different tables. I know it can be saved in single table with the help of keys. But in case any new device has to be added then i need to create new table for it. Which is not expected to be manually

Comment: I was applying a logic that table =  model. so if i wish to have different tables i need different models

Comment: Yes, a model equates to a table. But nothing in that explains why you need multiple tables for different devices.

Comment: Because each device may generate crore of records. If i add 500 device data  in one table can you imagine the situation. Thats why i want to maintain some house keeping. :-)

Answer (score 0):

From the comments it sounds like this is related to some performance concern about putting too much data into a single table. What you are describing sounds like an attempt at sharding (or horizontal partitioning) a single table by device. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shard_(database_architecture)

> Horizontal partitioning is a database design principle whereby rows of a database table are held separately, rather than being split into columns (which is what normalization and vertical partitioning do, to differing extents). Each partition forms part of a shard, which may in turn be located on a separate database server or physical location.

For Django related solutions to this problem you might consider using [django-horizon](https://github.com/uncovertruth/django-horizon) or [django-sharding](https://github.com/JBKahn/django-sharding). [architect](http://architect.readthedocs.io/features/partition/index.html) is an enhancement to the Django ORM which also supports partitions more like what you are describing.

> Table partitioning is a division of one table into several tables, called partitions, which still represent original table.